# Object of type User is not JSON serializable in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am customizing the API that I give when I send the get request. The following error occurred when the get request was sent after customizing the response value using GenericAPIView.

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 100, in render
    ret = json.dumps(
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\json.py", line 25, in dumps
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\encoders.py", line 67, in default
    return super().default(obj)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable
```

What's problem in my code? I can't solve this error. Please help me. Here is my code. Thanks in advance

views.py

```
class ReadPostView (GenericAPIView) :
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get (self, serializer) :
        serializer = self.serializer_class()
        posts = Post.objects.all()

        data = []

        for post in posts :
            comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)

            json = {
                'pk': post.pk,
                'author': {
                    'email': post.author_email,
                    'username': post.author_name,
                    'profile': post.author_profile
                },
                'like': post.liker.count, 
                'liker': post.liker,
                'text': post.text,
                'images': Image.objects.filter(post=post),
                'comments_count': comments.count(),
                'view': post.view,
                'viewer_liked': None,
                'tag': post.tag
            }
        data.append(json)

        return Response(data)
```

models.py

```
class Post (models.Model):
    author_name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='authorName', null=True)
    author_email = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='authorEmail', null=True)
    author_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='authorProfile', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=511, null=True)
    view = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    viewer = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='viewer', blank=True)
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    liker = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='liker', blank=True)

    def __str__ (self) :
        return self.title

class Image (models.Model) :
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

class Comment (models.Model) :
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: it's probably from this: `post.author_profile`. You will also get an error from this part: `Image.objects.filter(post=post)`. Can you add your post model to the question?

Comment: @NavidZarepak I add it !!

Comment: I dont understand why are you using "serializer_class = PostSerializer", when you are making json yourslef

Comment: @SuryaPratapRana Except for that, the same error occurs:(

Comment: why are adding multiple foreign key of same settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL . I think one is enogh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

**First,** you can't pass an instance or a list of instances to your JSON fields. `'email': post.author_email,`, `'username': post.author_name,`, `'profile': post.author_profile`, `'liker': post.liker,` and `'images': Image.objects.filter(post=post),`

To fix this you either have to create a serializer for their model and pass the serialized data instead or you have to just pass a serializable field of those models like `post.liker.email`

You can use DRF `ModelSerializer`'s to make a model serializer: [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

**Second,** you don't need all three fields `author_name`, `author_email`, and `author_profile` in your model. all of them are pointing to your default user model and you can access everywhere from one of them:

```
post.author_profile.email # will give you the user email
post.author_profile.first_name # will give you the user's first name
# and so on ...
```

**Third,** you can just use `ListAPIView` to generate a serialized list of your data: [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview)

You are doing the whole thing wrong here. Please consider looking at some more django and rest framework examples.

Comment: Thanks to you, I was able to completely correct the code that was a problem.